# Apple Pay - decrypt payment data

Tags: ios, encryption, ios8.1, applepay

I am trying to decrypt `paymentData` property of `PKPaymentToken` object upon a successful Apple Pay authorization.

I am trying to follow the instruction [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PaymentTokenJSON/PaymentTokenJSON.html), but I am stuck on step 2 of the decryption steps, which says:

> Use the value of the publicKeyHash key to determine which merchant
>   public key was used by Apple, and then retrieve the corresponding
>   merchant public key certificate and private key.

How do I do that?

Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how to compute the publicKeyHash in Ruby, given the Apple Pay certificate file downloaded from the Apple Developer Center.

```
require "base64"
require "digest"
require "openssl"

# set cert_file = path to the downloaded Apple Pay .cer file

cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read(cert_file)) 
# strip off the "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----" line at the start of the string
pem = cert.public_key.to_pem.split("\n").drop(1)
# strip off the "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----" line at the end of the string
pem = pem.take(pem.length - 1)

decoded = Base64.decode64(pem.join)
public_key_hash = Digest::SHA256.base64digest(decoded)
```

Comment: `Digest::SHA256.base64digest(cert.public_key.to_der)` also works.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `publicKeyHash` field is...a hash of your public key. As per the documentation, it's a SHA-256 hash of the X.509 encoded public key bytes of the merchant's certificate. You use this to determine which merchant identifier was used to sign the payment data (you probably only have one merchant identifier, in which case you'll already know which one is being used).

Comment: Ok, but what do I need to do in code? Do I need to have the merchant certificate in the app bundle, extract the public key from it, make SHA-256 on it and check that it equals to the publicKeyHash field? What about the other steps? How do I get the merchant's private key?

Comment: How did you generate the merchant certificates in the first place? You provide the private key to Apple when you generate the certs, so you should already have it.